# Not application installed use Uri record instead

Tags: android, nfc, android-applicationrecord

I'm creating a simple app to write and read NFC tags but I would like to know if is possible to use the URI record if the application is not install in the device instead of going to app store to look for the application using the AAR?

This is my NdefMessage code:

```
private NdefMessage getTagAsNdef(String uri) {     
      NdefRecord rtdUriRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(uri);

      return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { rtdUriRecord,
                    NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.example.nfcapplication")
         });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write a URI onto the NFC tag, a phone without a dedicated app will open that URI in the browser. Is this what you want to archieve?

Comment: No. I want to write a Uri and an AAR into the nfc tag and if the app is not present instead of taking me to the play store, just open the URI record with the default browser. I write the two records but if the app is not present it take me to the play store and that's not what I want. Thank's for looking into my question :D

Comment: The AAR serves only one purpose: go to the play store in case the matching app is not installed. Since you don't want to go to the play store, the URI is sufficient. Either your local app uses the URI or the URI ist sent to your browser (when no matching app ist present).

Comment: Well I guess there is not way of bypassing the play store call at the moment, Thanks for your help.